# ARM Template Load Balancer - InvalidTemplate-ResourceID: all function arguments must be string literals

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-load-balancer

*'Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': all function arguments must be string literals.'*

I have written an ARM template to deploy a Load Balancer and attach a Backend Pool to that.
When I deploy, I get the above error.

I am unable to distinguish any of the resourceID references as anything other than strings.
Hopefully somebody else notices what I've missed.

Resource code below:

Thank you!

```
``{ //APP ILB Create
"type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
"apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
"name": "\[concat(parameters('CompName'),'-APP-ILB')\]",
"location": "\[parameters('region')\]",
"sku": {
"name": "Standard",
"tier": "Regional"
},
"properties": {
"frontendIPConfigurations": \[
{
"name": "LoadBalancerFrontEnd",
"id": "\[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('APPILBName'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd'))\]",
"properties": {
"privateIPAddress": "\[concat('192.',parameters('VNET_IP'),'.0.101')\]",
"privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
"subnet": {
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('vnetName'))\]"
},
"privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
},
"zones": \[
"3",
"2",
"1"
\]
}
\],
"backendAddressPools": \[
{
"name": "\[variables('APPPOOLName')\]",
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', variables('APPILBName'), variables('APPPOOLName'))\]",
"properties": {
"loadBalancerBackendAddresses": \[
{
"name": "7f4ac3aa-9d43-4c8f-9c8f-3a20cfb276a1",
"properties": {
"ipAddress": "\[concat('192.',parameters('VNET_IP'),'0.6')\]",
"virtualNetwork": {
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'))\]"
}
}
},
{
"name": "918c1bbb-24bc-47ea-b7ad-bc3a80e877c4",
"properties": {
"ipAddress": "\[concat('192.',parameters('VNET_IP'),'0.7')\]",
"virtualNetwork": {
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('vnetName'))\]"
}
}
}
\]
}
}
\],
"loadBalancingRules": \[
{
"name": "DATA_RULE",
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('APPILBName'), '/loadBalancingRules/DATA_RULE')\]",
"properties": {
"frontendIPConfiguration": {
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('APPILBName'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd')\]"
},
"frontendPort": 50025,
"backendPort": 50025,
"enableFloatingIP": false,
"idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
"protocol": "Tcp",
"enableTcpReset": false,
"loadDistribution": "Default",
"disableOutboundSnat": true,
"backendAddressPool": {
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', concat(variables('APPILBName'), variables('APPPOOLName')))\]"
},
"probe": {
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('APPILBName'), '/probes/DATA_PROBE')\]"
}
}
}
\],
"probes": \[
{
"name": "DATA_PROBE",
"id": "\[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('APPILBName'), '/probes/DATA_PROBE')\]",
"properties": {
"protocol": "Tcp",
"port": 50025,
"intervalInSeconds": 5,
"numberOfProbes": 1,
"probeThreshold": 1
}
}
\],
"inboundNatRules": \[\],
"outboundRules": \[\],
"inboundNatPools": \[\]
}
}`
```

`

Already Tried:
Removed all concatenations in ResourceID references - no change.
Converted all concatenated text into variables, and replaced references - no change.
Compared all resourceID references with Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: What does `Apppoolname`, `AppILBname` variables have? Make sure that `variable(Apppoolname)` is returning string value. Can you confirm here. @dchambers6222

Comment: Here are the definitions for those two variables:

        "APPILBName": [
            "[concat(parameters('CompName'),'-APP-ILB')]"
        ],
        "APPPOOLName": [
            "[concat(parameters('CompName'), '_APP_POOL')]"
        ]
And CompName is defined as a string.

Answer (score 0):

> *'Unable to evaluate template language function 'resourceId': all function arguments must be string literals.'*

The above error means that the arguments in `resourceID` must be string literals.

Considering all `resourceId` functions in your code:

The `frontendIPConfigurations` block has a `resourceId` function as well as a `concat` function. Check the value of `variables('APPILBName')`, because if it is not a string, the issue may occur.

As previously stated, ensure that the variables passed to the `resourceID` function of `loadBalancingRules` and `backendAddressPools` doesn't have any conflict as above.

Instead of passing it as

```bash
"id": "\[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('APPILBName'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd'))\]",
```

Store the pool name or any user defined variable in a variable argument like `APPILBName` and pass it to the `resourceID` function.

```bash
"id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', variables('APPILBName'), variable('frontendIPConfigurations'))]",
```

Referring to the ARM template from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-load-balancer-standard-internal-template), I tried deploying a load balancer with the backend address pools and was successful as shown.

```bash
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
      "apiVersion": "2021-05-01",
      "name": "[variables('loadBalancer')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard"
      },
      "properties": {
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              },
              "privateIPAddress": "10.0.2.6",
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static"
            },
            "name": "LoadBalancerFrontend"
          }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "BackendPool1"
          }
        ],
        "loadBalancingRules": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/frontendIpConfigurations', variables('loadBalancer'), 'LoadBalancerFrontend')]"
              },
              "backendAddressPool": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/backendAddressPools', variables('loadBalancer'), 'BackendPool1')]"
              },
              "probe": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/probes', variables('loadBalancerName'), 'lbprobe')]"
              },
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "frontendPort": 80,
              "backendPort": 80,
              "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 20
            },
            "name": "lbrule"
          }
        ],
        "probes": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "port": 80,
              "intervalInSeconds": 15,
              "numberOfProbes": 2
            },
            "name": "lbprobe"
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

[image]

[image]